# need help in convert php code to mysql command

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, command

I've table called (rr) with 3 columns id int, name varchar 100, and cnt int.

I wrote php code to loop each record depending on cnt:

```
< ?php
$getAll = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM rr");
while ($v = mysql_fetch_array($getAll)){
    for( $i=1; $i <= $v['cnt']; $i++ ){
        echo $i ." - ". $v['name'] ." - ". $v['cnt'] . "<br />";
    }
}
? >
```

I need to convert this code to MySQL command to get same result or creating a view with a same results.
Can any body help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you mean a MySQL command? MySQL is a database and so it won't be able to print anything to your browser?

Comment: This is a presentation issue. It should not be handled by the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well its better to handle it in front side. If still you want it in a result via sql query in mysql, then you can use comething like concat in select statement. Just try to concatenate the string as per your requirement in the select statement.